# Polish spaces and analytic sets

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets, measurable-functions

1. Can we conclude that an analytic subset $A$ of a Polish space $X$ is also Polish?
2. Let $\mathcal{M}(R^d)$ denotes the family of Borel probability measures on $R^d$ equipped with the Lévy-Prokhorov metric. Is it true that $\mathcal{M}(R^d)$ is an analytic space?

Comment: For 1, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space#Properties : only $G_\delta$ subsets are Polish.

Comment: For 2, $\mathcal{M}(R^d)$ is even Polish.

Comment: $M(R^d)$ is analytic?

Comment: Yes, every Polish space is analytic.